# Google Charts displays wrong month

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I've got a google line chart which shows the correct line; but the annotation of the Date is off by one month exactly. The json data has the correct date; but somehow google charts transforms it:
[image: chart with wrong date]

Anybody an idea why this happens?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

no mistake, the correct month is being displayed

when using the following date constructor, **the months are zero based**...

`Date(year, month, day, hour, min, sec, mill)`

see following snippet...

```js
console.log(new Date(2016,  0, 1)); // <-- Jan
console.log(new Date(2016,  1, 1)); // <-- Feb
console.log(new Date(2016, 11, 1)); // <-- Dec
```

following is another snippet to demonstrate using json with google charts...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      "cols": [
        {"label": "Date", "type": "date"}
      ],
      "rows": [
        {"c": [{"v": "Date(2016,0,28,15,0,0)"}]},
        {"c": [{"v": "Date(2016,1,28,15,0,0)"}]},
        {"c": [{"v": "Date(2016,2,28,15,0,0)"}]},
        {"c": [{"v": "Date(2016,3,28,15,0,0)"}]},
        {"c": [{"v": "Date(2016,4,28,15,0,0)"}]},
        {"c": [{"v": "Date(2016,5,28,15,0,0)"}]},
        {"c": [{"v": "Date(2016,6,28,15,0,0)"}]},
        {"c": [{"v": "Date(2016,7,28,15,0,0)"}]},
        {"c": [{"v": "Date(2016,8,28,15,0,0)"}]},
        {"c": [{"v": "Date(2016,9,28,15,0,0)"}]},
        {"c": [{"v": "Date(2016,10,28,15,0,0)"}]},
        {"c": [{"v": "Date(2016,11,28,15,0,0)"}]},
      ]
    });

    var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data);
  },
  packages:['table']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

following is a php snippet to create the json date using the above constructor

```
<?php
$date1 = new DateTime();
$date2 = "Date(".date_format($date1, 'Y').", ".((int) date_format($date1, 'm') - 1).", ".date_format($date1, 'd').", ".date_format($date1, 'H').", ".date_format($date1, 'i').", ".date_format($date1, 's').")";

echo $date2;
?>
```

[here is a php fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ej1n-wt61) to test the above snippet...

Comment: It helped! Thank you

Comment: You saved my day! Zero based month?! Why?.... A rhetorical question. This is JavaScript.